# How do you get a list of MS Access data types?

Tags: c#, ms-access, list, combobox, oledb

I am trying to list data types from Microsoft Access 2000-2007 (depending on the MS Access database version) in a combobox for a C# program. How can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: Do you want Access data types or Jet/ACE data types? Likely since you're using C#, you want only Jet/ACE data types, but it could be the database you're working with was created by Access and uses Access-specific datatypes (which are usually regular Jet/ACE data types with extended attributes, e.g., the Hyperlink field, which is a memo field with a particular setting that indicates to Access that it's a hyperlink field and not just a regular memo field).

Comment: Yes, I want to use specific MS Access data types. If I am not mistaken is ACE compatible with MS Access 2000-2007? I am trying to make my program capable of opening MS Access 2000-2007 databases. So for example, if I open a MS Access 2003 I wish my program to be capable of using the datatypes of any data specific to MS Access 2003. If I open a MS Access 2007 database it will be for datatypes of any data for MS Access 2007...

Comment: I am closing this question because it was not thorough enough and I want to know some other things... here is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172617/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to interrogate the engine at run time to enumerate the data types it supports. For example, DAO will not reveal some of the Jet 4.0 data types such as `NCHAR` and `BINARY`; ADO will reveals data types that the Access database engine has never supported; only ACEDAO will reveal multivalued types.

I think you need to know in advance the data types each version of the engine supports then select the appropriate set at run time.

Jet 4.0 data types (Access2000 to 2003 inclusive) and the various synonyms can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015(office.10).aspx) (should also give some hints about which types are new to Jet 4.0, just in case you need to support earlier versions of the engine).

ACE (Access2007) added an Attachment type; also multivalued ("complex") types in order to support SharePoint lists: I think you will need to decide for yourself whether multivalued types are distinct types or merely variations on existing types. There are some details in the [Access2007 Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HA100140981033.aspx).

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should add a reference to ACEDAO and use that?

Comment: Can I use ACEDAO with MS Access 2000-2003 or is that only for MS Access 2007?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DataTypeEnum

Of course, you'll need to add a reference, and I absolutely hate adding reference to Office because you get tied to a version of Office,and I hate updating code every time we upgrade.

Comment: DAO will only give you the pre-Access2000 data types plus DECIMAL (but not the scale and precision values), won't give you e.g. NCHAR and BINARY data types from Jet 4.0 (Access2000 onwards) or multi-value types (Access2007 onwards).

Comment: Can't DAO be used with late binding, which would mean you wouldn't need a reference? Secondly, if you're working with files created in both Access 2007 and with earlier versions, you'll need DAO-version-specific checks, since DAO 3.6 (Jet 4.0, or Access 2000, 2002 and 2003) was superseded by the Jet/ACE-specific DAO version that shipped with Access 2007 and added some new data types (not very useful ones -- mostly for Sharepoint compatibility).

Comment: "Can't DAO be used with late binding" -- no. DAO 3.6 will not reveal NCHAR and binary data types.