# How can I get all the data types specific for a certain version of MS Access or/and every versions of MS Access?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, version-control, types

I am trying to list data types from Microsoft Access 2000-2007 (depending on the MS Access database version) in a combobox for a C# program. I want my program to be capable of opening MS Access 2000-2007 databases. If I open a MS Access 2003 I wish my program to be capable of using the datatypes of any data specific to MS Access 2003 and list those data types in a combobox. If I open a MS Access 2007 database it will be for datatypes of any data for MS Access 2007... I was wondering if I could use ACEDAO for that (is ACEDAO only compatible for MS Access 2007?). Also, how can I get all the data types specific for a certain version of MS Access or/and every versions of MS Access (2000-2007 in my case)?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked here yesterday?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167740/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-ms-access-data-types/1167847#1167847

Comment: The question was not thorough enough and I want to know if ACEDAO is compatible for any MS Access version. I voted to close the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACEDAO is backwardly compatible with all previous versions of Jet. But the compatibility is provided in different ways. For instance, if you look directly at the object model of ACEDAO, you'll see that there's both a Field data type and a Field2 data type. Within Access 2007, you don't see that. My surmise is that the Field data type is for MDBs (Jet 4 and earlier), and the Field2 data type is for ACCDB, because the ACCDB has new data types that have properties and methods lacking in the earlier field type.

For instance, the Field2 data type has the AppendOnly property that is used in append-only memo fields, a new feature in ACE. Another new property is IsComplex, which I'm guessing is there to support the new multi-value data type. There's also LoadFromFile and SaveToFile methods that I don't recognize the purpose of.

Now, that's just one object in the DAO library where there are variations depending on what file format you're using. I haven't looked for other such variations, but they might be there.

So, you'd still need to know what applied to different versions, even though ACEDAO is going to give you a superset that will be able to operate on all older versions. If you only need to work with ACCDB and Jet 4 MDBs, I'd think ACEDAO is going to suffice.

But, I'm just guessing based on what I understand it is that you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the ACEDAO version of DataTypeEnum lists all data types that have everr been available (though you'd have to look for a variation of dbMemo to be able to distinguish a Hyperlink if you consider this to be a distinct data type.

However, it also lists additional types it seemingly does not support: `dbfloat` (21) as distinct from `dbDouble` (7); `dbTime` (22) as distinct from `dbDate` (8); `dbNumeric` (19) as distinct from `dbDouble` (20); distinct types for `dbVarBinary`, `dbBinary` and `dbLongBinary`.

Also, I don't think it is possible to interrogate a particular version of the engine at run time to enumerate the data types  supports.

Therefore, I don't think simply listing the types from ACEDAO enumeration will be very useful. Rather, I think you need to know in advance the data types each version of the engine supports then select the appropriate set at run time.

Jet 4.0 data types (Access2000 to 2003 inclusive) and the various synonyms can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015(office.10).aspx); it should also give some hints about which types are new to Jet 4.0 i.e. to help you support earlier versions of the engine.

ACE (Access2007) added an [Attachment type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HA012138521033.aspx); it also added [multivalued ("complex") types](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HA100140981033.aspx) which you will need to decide for yourself whether these are distinct types (or merely variations on existing data types) based on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It just occurred to me re-reading this that it's important to realize that Jet/ACE needs to support these other data types because it's often used as a conduit to other database engines. When Jet/ACE is handling an ODBC data source, the fact that it can distinguish data types that Jet/ACE itself does not distinguish/support is a really good thing, don't you think?

Comment: @David W. Fenton: No, I think it's a lot simpler than that: I think DAO has types in excess of those required for Jet/ACE in order to be able to support other data sources without involving the Jet/ACE engine at all. I think you'll find that many Access users like to use DAO for simple SQL Server data scenarios due to familiarity and ease of use. When the Jet/ACE engine uses non-Jet/ACE sources I think it's a case of a simple mapping process; I doubt it uses DAO to achieve this (rather will use info from the driver/provider). Look at ADO's DataTypeEnum: DAO's alone couldn't map enough types!